# Difficult with a query and join

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data, querydsl

I have entity `Lots` witch has a `city_execution` or a `city_execution` (Exclusive or).

If `city_execution` is `null`so `region_execution` is not and the same  goes for `region_execution`.

Also a region have many cities.

here is My table :

```
Lots ( #id_lot , ... , *city_execution* , *region_execution* )
```

`city_execution` FK references `id_city`
`region_execution` FK references `id_region`

```
cities ( #id_city, ... , *id_region* )

regions ( #id_region , ... )
```

Now i want that query in `hibernate` or `jpa` or `querydsl` it doesn't matter :

if a user enter a `region` as parametr in search form i can get all `lots` even those with `cities` in the `region` specify by the user ?

I try this but i got nothing :

```
select lot from lot 
    left join fetch  on lot.city_execution as city
    left join fetch  on lot.region_execution as region
    where city.id_region = ?
```

i'm using `querydsl` so it can be write like this :

```
    JPAQuery query = new JPAQuery(entityManager).from(lot)

            .leftJoin( lot.regions ).fetch()
            .leftJoin( lot.cities).fetch()

            .where(lot.city_execution.region.id_region.eq(region_value_enter_by_user))
            .distinct();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a `querydsl` problem because it generate a extra `join cross` to my query.

So we resolved the issue by this changing

```
  JPAQuery query = new JPAQuery(entityManager).from(lot)

            .leftJoin( lot.regions ).fetch()
            .leftJoin( lot.cities).fetch()

            .where(lot.city_execution.region.id_region.eq(region_value_enter_by_user))
            .distinct();
```

to

```
  JPAQuery query = new JPAQuery(entityManager).from(lot)

            .leftJoin( lot.regions ).fetch()
            .leftJoin( lot.cities , city).fetch()

            .where(city.region.id_region.eq(region_value_enter_by_user))
            .distinct();
```

by adding a alias `city` `.leftJoin( lot.cities , city).fetch()` and changing `lot.city_execution`  to `city` in the `where`